# How to tell tramp to not ask me about autosave on local directory?

Tags: tramp

Sometimes, when I edit a file with tramp, it asks me:

"Autosave file on local temporary directory, do you want to continue?(yes or no)"

I want to continue in any case. How can I disable this prompt?

Comment: I set `setq tramp-auto-save-directory "~/emacs/tramp-autosave"`, I am not sure, but I think with this there is not such a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Tramp manual:

Per default, TRAMP asks for confirmation if a ‘root’-owned remote
backup, auto-save or lock file has to be written to your local temporary
directory.  If you want to suppress this confirmation question, set user
option ‘tramp-allow-unsafe-temporary-files’ to ‘t’.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that question is that sensitive contents might be inadvertently exposed through backup files saved into the default temporary location -- usually `temporary-file-directory = /tmp/`, but, please, check also `tramp-auto-save-directory`. So, think twice before disabling that warning.

Although there might be performance implications, a better alternative is ([emacs manual section 4.21](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Auto_002dsave-File-Lock-and-Backup.html)):

> Set auto-save-file-name-transforms to nil to save auto-saved files to
> the same directory as the original file.